# Manage multiple windows 10 machines without GPO

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, azure-activedirectory, intune

So we have a "corporate" networks with all laptops, about 65-70 of them. We do not have and do not plan to have an on premises active directory/domain controllers. By requirement of our jobs we need a total cloud-based solution. We have leveraged Azure as best as we can with InTune, but is far from perfect.

All of the laptops were Azure AD Domain Joined -- and are NOT managed by the InTune APP but rather the Azure AD Join MDM service tied to InTune. I was wondering what are other ways to apply "policies" such as Screen Timeout, Ask for Password on Wake, Setting System-Wide Application Defaults via batch script or installer? I have accomplished much of what I want with batch scripting but haven't found much on how to set app defaults and apply basic settings to Local Group Policy. Provision packages simply do not work. I have tested NUMEROUS package combinations with the Configuration Designer and just get constant errors trying to install the packages.

Yes, I know Azure AD is not a true AD replacement, but we do not have the resources to utilize on On-Prem solution, so we need to come up with creative ways to apply base policies before we hand the end user their machine.

Comment: Default app can be set with `assoc` and `ftype` commands. Also with `dism` command. [Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825038.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! This is REALLY useful :) Now just to figure out commands/scripts to manipulate local GPO.